# field_with_errors not being applied on reform form object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reform

I am using the [reform gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/reform) to create a form object.  Typically in rails: when a validation fails on a form: the `field_with_errors` class wraps the label and input of the invalid fields.  This is not occurring in my reform form object.

Here is the class for the form object:

```
# app/forms/signup_form.rb
class SignupForm < Reform::Form
  include Reform::Form::ActiveRecord
  include Composition

  model :user, on: :user 

  property :id,               on: :user
  property :name,             on: :user

  property :blog_id,          on: :blog, from: :id
  property :user_id,          on: :blog
  property :title,            on: :blog

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true

end
```

And here is the actual form:

```
# app/views/users/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(signup_form, url: signup_form_path(signup_form.model[:user]), method: signup_form_method(signup_form.model[:user])) do |form| %>

  <% if signup_form.errors.size > 0 %>
    <div>
      <p><%= pluralize(signup_form.errors.size, "error") %> prohibited the data from persisting</p>
      <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
      <ul>
        <% signup_form.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.hidden_field(:user_id, value: form.object.user_id) %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name, "* Name" %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title, "* Title" %>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is what the form looks like prior to being submitted:

[image: prior submissions]

If I click the `Create User` button without filling anything out, it fails because the `Name` and `Title` fields are required.  It does properly fail, but the invalid labels and fields are not wrapped with `field_with_errors` and thus are not styled with the rails default `field_with_errors` styling.  It looks like this:

[image: after submission]

---

**Applying the approved answer for a complete code solution of this question:**

```
<div class="field <%= form_obj_field_with_errors(form.object.errors[:name].join(',')) %>">
  <%= form.label :name, "* Name" %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field <%= form_obj_field_with_errors(form.object.errors[:title].join(',')) %>">
  <%= form.label :title, "* Title" %>
  <%= form.text_field :title %>
</div>
```

And here is the helper:

```
def form_obj_field_with_errors(error_msg)
  return unless error_msg.present?
  return 'field_with_errors'
end
```

---

**Update!!!**

It turns out that the above solution is unnecessary.  Reform **does** properly apply `field_with_errors`.  My error was that I was using the latest, unstable version of reform in my rails project.

Previously I specified this gem to bring reform into my rails project:

```
gem 'reform-rails', '0.2.0rc1'
```

That version was unstable.  I switched to the latest stable version, and it all worked as expected.  No need to add `field_with_errors` by hand:

```
gem 'reform-rails', '~> 0.1.7'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use [simple_form_for](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem which will create the entire component (label, input and inline error message):

```
<%= simple_form_for signup_form do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :name %>
```

Otherwise you need to add the inline error messages yourself, for example:

```
<%= form.object.errors[:name].join(', ') %>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Please approve my extended example of usage in the question's code.

Comment: I think the answer as is answers the question succinctly. Most people aren't going to be interested in your specific code but the answer to the question which they can apply and then do their own refactoring for reuse.

Comment: Ok, if you won't put it in the answer, then I will put it in the question itself.  I think a complete answer to the question's code can be helpful.

Comment: Ahh!  Turns out my issue was that I was using the latest, unstable version of reform.  I was using `gem 'reform-rails', '0.2.0rc1'`.  I switched it to: `gem 'reform-rails', '~> 0.1.7'` and it worked as expected.  No need to add `field_with_errors` by hand anymore.